# Swift - Parse.Com - LogIn - 'selector' not found

Tags: authentication, swift, parse-platform

I amd making a swift app, and I use Parse.com for a cdn. I am making the login part of my app. Currently, there is an error which it says `Missing argument for parameter 'selector' in call`.
This is my code:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password) { (user, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Error " + error.code + ": " + error.message, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles:nil)
            alert.show()
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a type inference ambiguity, mapping the call to another method overload.

Try using the explicit parameter instead of a trailing closure, like this:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Error " + error.code + ": " + error.message, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles:nil)
        alert.show()
    } else {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to define the username and password like this (for example):

```
let pass: String = object["password"] as String

let user: String = object["username"] as String

PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(user, password: pass) {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if user != nil {
            println("Cool")
        } else {
          println("User nil")
        }
 }
```